# QList acting strange

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I don't have much experience with Qt but somehow I think this is acting strange.
Compiled with VS2005:

```
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry(const QString& aName, bool checked) : 
        name(aName), isChecked(checked)
    { 
        // empty 
    };

    Entry(const Entry& entry) : 
        name(entry.name), isChecked(entry.isChecked)
    { 
        // empty 
    };

    Entry& operator=(const Entry& entry)
    {
        name = entry.name;
        isChecked = entry.isChecked;
        return *this;
    }

    QString name;
    bool isChecked;
};

typedef QList<conduit::Entry> EntryVector;
```

When using EntryVector in the following lines, the entry in QList becomes a bad pointer:

```
void EntryWidget::setEntries(QStringList& names)
{
    QStringList::iterator member;
    EntryVector list;

    for (member = names.begin(); member != names.end(); ++member)
    {
        Entry entry(*member, false);
        list.append(entry);
    }

    m_model.setEntryData(list);
}
```

Somehow, entry.name in the list will become a bad pointer. My understanding is that QList should be able to support any data in its template, but for some reason that I yet do not understand this does not work. Everything works just fine if I use a STL Vector.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: "Somehow, entry.name in the list will become a bad pointer."
What do you mean by this? As you don't use pointers, I don't see how that could happen.
Can you show the code that accesses the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, and came looking for anwsers.

I though my code was misbehaving, when it's not.

VS2005 debugger doesn't show you the things in QList correctly.

And as davmac suggested, when you print the stuff out, it works fine.

And davmac, please don't point out that he might have a memory corruption when the guy gives you a piece of code to try. If you can't try it with the same setup, that's another thing.

Comment: The poster didn't say anything about using the VS2005 debugger; he just said that 'the entry in QList becomes a bad pointer' as if this was a statement of fact other than just what the debugger had showed. I wasn't the only person confused by this, either; see the comment by Freank Osterfeld.

Comment: Well he said he had compiled it with VS2005. I thought it a fair assumption that he was using the VS2005 debugger. And I know for a fact that VS2005 debugger doesn't know how to show the memory of some Qt containers. What it says is "bad pointer".

Comment: Sure, but I don't use the VS2005 debugger and the question does say "compiled with VS2005" but doesn't say anything about using a debugger. To me, "bad pointer" implies a corruption and the most likely cause seemed to be that the heap was being corrupted elsewhere. There's clearly nothing wrong with the code that was posted so whether I can try it with VS2005 or not seems irrelevant, unless it was a VS2005 bug which I considered highly unlikely. If the question had been clearer then I could have given a better answer.

Comment: Sure the question could have been better, the person didn't write the pure error texts here, he made his own assumptions on what was happening. This is just my personal standpoint, I don't like people who assume memory corruption too easily. You need to tell them how to tell it really is a memory corruption and how to debug to find it and such. Just saying "It's most likely a memory corruption" is lazy from my perspective. Feel free to feel different on the matter. But if you really want to change my opinion, just give good reasons why and maybe i'll like them more than my own.

Comment: I myself have wasted time trying to isolate a fault in a certain piece of code, only to find it was caused by memory corruption (write past end of array or similar) which occurred prior, on multiple occasions. A pointer "suddenly going bad" for no apparent reason is a classic sign of this, so the mention of memory corruption is not without justification. I'm not sure why I should have to persuade *you* of anything. If you don't agree with something I said in my answer, explain *your* reasoning.

Comment: I think I already did, atleast try to. I don't see the constructive point in the comment "Most likely, some part.." blame on memory corruption. Why is it most likely if it works with stl vectors? Why not just "memory corruption is a possibility, here's how to check for that". If you have expertise in memory corruptions, share it for others. Some time ago I asked for help with a library made by someone else, he just stated that there are no errors in his code and i'v made a memory corruption in mine. There wasn't, there was a weird bug in his, which I found after getting the source code.

Comment: I don't see the point in this, we just have different opinions. Let's just leave it at that?

Comment: The fact that works with stl vectors to me made it all the more likely that memory corruption was the culprit - different classes, different memory layouts, different response to corruption.

You've now asked me to share my expertise in memory corruptions, but in your original answer above you explicitly asked me *not* to do that.

I'm sorry that you had a bad experience where someone gave you bad advice, but that doesn't mean that this same advice is bad in other situations.

I'll agree that the use of "Most likely" was a bad choice of words.
Beyond that, yes, I'm fine to let this go.

Answer (score 0):

"entry.name" isn't a pointer - it's declared as a QString, here:

```
public: QString name;
```

So, what do you mean by "entry.name will become a bad pointer"?

Most likely, some other part of your program is causing a memory corruption.

Comment: BadPtr is what VS debugger shows when debugging through the setEntries method. No other thread is active, so I do not see any reason why that as soon as the entry is added to the list, and after the copy constructor has been called, the list no longer holds a valid entry for the name. This happens as soon as 'list.append(entry);' is called. The copied Entry in QList just looses the name QString in it.

Comment: I've never used the VS debugger, but: I suspect that it's not entry.name which is the bad pointer, but rather entry itself, because it has gone out of scope (it is in scope at the start of the loop, and goes out of scope at the end of the loop; there's a brief point of time between iterations of the loop where it is arguably out-of-scope).

Try a more traditional debugging approach - print out the contents of the list to the console after each time you add an entry. I'm sure you'll see that the entries are being added correctly, and the Entry in the QList is not losing the name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that QStringList makes a depth-copy of the Strings in its copy-ctor.

And we know QList makes no depth-copy. [see QList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#QList-3) and [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.)

So, at the call of

```
void EntryWidget::setEntries(QStringList& names) {...}
```

Strings in *names* are copied.

But when you set the new *Entry*-List to the model,

```
m_model.setEntryData(list);
```

the *list* is not copied into *mmodel.xy*.

Now you can access *mmodel.xy*, but the strings you assign in *setEntries(..)* are already deleted.
They lost their scope, when you leave the *setEntries(..)* method.

**Note:**
QString is a reference pointer to a String. This is called "implicit sharing" .
And all containers in Qt have the concept of lazy-evaluation.
(Probably except the *QStringList*, which makes a depth-copy. This is perhaps a little bug in Qt. I can it only say 100% if I see the .cpp)

qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstringlist.html#QStringList-3